# React-Native get state in const

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to take state.photo in const but return to me ; connat read property 'photo' of undefined.

How can i fix this problem ?

```
class App extends Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props); 
            this.state={photo:"url"} 

        }

    const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
        {       
          Login:{screen: Login },
          EditProfile:{screen:EditProfileScreen},
          Main:{screen: MainScreen , navigationOptions: {
           headerTitle: (
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', width:100+"%"}}>
               <AutoHeightImage width={36}  source={  this.state.photo != null ? {uri:url.getURL()+"/"+this.state.photo } : require('./img/user.png')} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            ),
            headerLeft: null,
            headerTintColor: "white",
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#34495e'
            } }},

        }, { initialRouteName:"Login "});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you won't be able to define a `StackNavigator` inside a component.

What you might want to do is override the `navigationOptions` within the component, as shown [here](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/using-params-in-title-v2).(You can also read more about the code here. ***[React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html)***)  And then pass in your `photo` variable as a prop to the component. Or better yet, as a `navigationParam` when routing to the desired screen. Check [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html) on how to implement `navigationParam`.